# Facing problems in binary search in c

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bsearch(int ar[],int n,int key)
{
    int s=0;
    int e=n-1;
    
    while(s<=e){
        int mid=(e+s)/2;
        if(mid==key){
            return mid;
        }
        else if(key<mid){
            e=mid-1;
        }
        else if(key>mid){
            s=mid+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I made the function for the binary search

```
int main()
{
    int n,key;
    int ar[n];
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("ar[%d]= ",i);
        scanf("%d",&ar[i]);
        
    }
    printf("Enter key>> \n");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    printf("%d is the index",bsearch(ar,n,key));
    return 0;
}
```

Then I inputted an sorted array but with repetitions. Shown in the following image.

[image: input in terminal]

The output is coming as **3 is the index**.
But it should as come as **6 is the index**.

Comment: FIY: `bsearch()` is a Standard defined function. Whether you `#include <stdlib.h>` it is a bad idea to write your own function using that identifier.

Comment: change `key == mid` to `key == ar[mid]` because mid is the index and you are looking for `ar[mid]` value. While calculating `mid` you should look for overflow errors. Instead of `(e+s)/2` you should use `e + (e-s)/2` or `(s+e) >> 1`. This will prevent overflow errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mid` is an index of element, not a value. So, I have corrected your function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int bsearch(int ar[], int n, int key)
{
    int s=0;
    int e=n-1;
    
    while(s <= e){
        int mid = (e + s) / 2;
        if(key == ar[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
        else if(key < ar[mid]) {
            e = mid-1;
        }
        else if(key > ar[mid]) {
            s = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Consistency (a very important part of programming) suggests that the conditions `if(ar[mid]==key)` – `else if(key<ar[mid])` — `else if(key>ar[mid])` should all be written with `key` first (or perhaps all with `key` last, but that requires more care).